# Google play how to invite a player to a room

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have this code:

```
RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
rtmConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(opponentId);
rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(null);
mGamesClient.createRoom(rtmConfigBuilder.build());
```

But I am getting error code **6004** which is **STATUS_MULTIPLAYER_ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION**

**This multiplayer operation is not valid, and the server rejected it. Check the logs for more information.**

I think it's because of the **addPlayersToInvite** method because I read the following in the android docs...

```
public RoomConfig.Builder addPlayersToInvite (String... playerIds)

Add one or more player IDs to invite to the room. This should be set only when calling create(GoogleApiClient, RoomConfig)

Parameters
playerIds   One or more player IDs to invite to the room.
Returns
The builder instance.
```

Note how it says **this should only be set when calling create(GoogleApiClient, RoomConfig)** but I dont know how to call method or what to do.

So my question basically is this: I have the id of the player I have invited, I now want to create a room for the player and me. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just stumbled upon this one, so sorry for digging this up, but for future generations:

you cannot set autoMatchCriteria to null:

`rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(null);`

also, you actually cannot set the minAutoMatchPlayers nor maxAutoMatchPlayers to 0.

the best way to avoid this is to do a zero-check and NOT to use setAutoMatchCriteria() at all if minAutoMatchPlayers or maxAutoMatchPlayers is equal to 0:

```
final ArrayList<String> invitees = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;

int minAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
int maxAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);

if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
    autoMatchCriteria =  RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
} else {
    autoMatchCriteria = null;
}

RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
    roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
}
roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
```

Comment: At this date, Multiplayer.EXTRA_PLAYERS have been removed from the API... When I find the new constant, I will add a comment

Comment: Replacement should be : Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS

Comment: Edited to work with the API changes mentioned by @Arnaud